# Why Meteor.bindEnvironment is not wrapping callback functions by default?

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback, meteorite, asynccallback

This question how to use Meteor.bindEnvironment is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235052/warning-error-meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-when-call-method-on-se?answertab=active#tab-top). My question is Why callback functions are not wrapped by Meteor.bindEnvironment in default? Does it effect performance?

(I added this as a comment in the said answer but it remains not answered)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended for developers to ask questions that can be answered, not philosophize about why something is or isn't done a certain way.

Comment: @BrianShamblen okay. Thanks for the comment. I actually wanted to know whether it reduces performance if I wrap a function with Meteor.bindEnvironment. I'd refactor the question to explicitly say so :)